Conformal time and conformal coordinates in a NON-COMOVING frame?
Lets consider an uniformly expanding universe with scale parameter $a(\tau)$ where $\tau$ is comoving time. Then we can write the metric as conformally transformed
$$\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}=a^{2}g_{\mu\nu}$$
where time is now in terms of conformal time:
$$d\eta=\frac{d\tau}{a(\tau)}$$ This is how every book I've ever come across treats this; however it is undesirable in that it forces a particular frame of reference (i.e. the comoving frame). In a general frame the scale parameter is a function of space and time coordinates (for example the dipole effect in the observed hubble redshift as seen from earth comes from this). So In a general frame we would have a set of four conformal coordinates that also would have components that aren't conformally transformed? I would love some help here.
Another way of saying this is that the scale parameter by construction introduces a nondegenerate line field everywhere which in a general frame will have components mixing with the space and time components.
